# Java - Flex 4 AIR 2.0 Native Process

Tags: java, air, process, flex4

i'm using Flex 4 Native Process to interact with Java to connect to a remote server using PHP.

I tried this example i found on the internet to connect Flex with Java:

Flex:

```
    protected function windowedApplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event: FlexEvent): void
        {
            var info:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            info.executable = new File("C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe");
            info.workingDirectory = File.applicationDirectory;

            var args: Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
            args.push("-cp", "../bin", "scanner.Main");
            info.arguments = args;
            process = new NativeProcess();
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onDataOutput);
            process.start(info);
        }

        private function onDataOutput(event: ProgressEvent): void 
        {
            var message:String = process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
            Alert.show(message);
        }
```

Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNext("hello|stop"))
    {
        input = scanner.next();
        if (input.equals("hello"))
        {
            System.out.println("hello flex! ... from java");
        }
        else if (input.equals("stop"))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And it works perfect.

But when i try calling the Java method that connects to the remote server, switching the line `System.out.println("hello flex! ... from java");` for the name of the method, it dies (does nothing).

I'm new to the Native Process concept, but researching on the web i found out that you need to send the libraries as arguments that your project uses.

I need some help on how to do so.

The Java project uses Http and JSon libraries.
How do i add those to the arguments? and do i need to add the JRE System libraries too?

PS: The java method works fine if i execute it from eclipse.

Thank you.

Edit: Tried it with a Jar file

```
    var file:File = new File("C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/");
            file = file.resolvePath("bin/javaw.exe");

            var arg:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;
            arg.push("-jar");
            arg.push(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("prueba3.jar").nativePath);
            arg.push("-Djava.library.path=C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\\libhttp");

            var npInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            npInfo.executable = file;
            npInfo.arguments = arg;

            process = new NativeProcess();          
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onStandardOutputData);
            process.start(npInfo);
```

and adding the library path, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a AMFPHP service, and connect directly to PHP with AS3